# NameError for using timeit in python

Tags: python, timeit

I got `NameError` when I try to run this codes."global name j is not defined". How can I fix it?

```
def test(j):
    for i in range(j):
        j = i**2

if __name__=='__main__':
    from timeit import Timer
    j = 30
    t = Timer("test(j)","from __main__ import test")
    print( t.timeit(j))
```

Comment: Why keep using the variable `j` in many different contexts?

Comment: `from __main__ import test, j` works and you have too many `j` s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Timer` doesn't know about `j`. You need to do something like `"test(%d)" % j` (or `from __main__ import j` or put the definition of `j` inside the string, too).

Also, the argument to `timeit` is different from the argument to your `test` function (so the different uses of `j` are probably not what you should do or mean). The timeit argument gives the number of executions for the test function.

p.s. Note that you need to indent any code in your question to get it formatted

p.p.s. There used to be a comment here about not using `from __main__ import` but that actually does work!

Comment: `from __main__ import test` works, try it. Is it preferred? Dunno, but would welcome an explanation why not.